# empty response from a WCF call even though Soap has values

Tags: soap, wcf

when im invoking a service from my code and from WCFTestClient, im getting a null response, but when im using another Tool (SoapUI), im getting a valid response back.

Anyone has any idea why this is happening?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It is probably that your WCFTestClient is not sending the same request as SoapUI.

You need to use WCF Tracing or other network logging tool to find out what is happening.